# Error in ARQoid

Tags: android, sparql

I'm working on an Android project that uses Androjena library. I have imported all the necessary jar files from Androjena library, including ARQoid jar file.

But when I execute SPARQL Query it display the following error message:

`"Lexical Error line 1 , columun (301). Encountered: " " (32) after: "EXISTS""` but when I run it in Java it works fine.

Could you suggest me the possible solution?

The query statement is here:

```
"prefix foaf1: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>" +
"prefix res: <http://EMIS.org/Group#> " +
"prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>" +                       
"SELECT ?name ?phone ?mid " +
"WHERE {" +
"?y foaf1:member ?x; rdf:id \"G1\" ." +`enter code here`
"?x res:LocatedIn \"Bldg2\" ." +
"?x foaf1:name ?name ." +
"?x rdf:id ?mid ." +
"?x foaf1:phone ?phone ." +
"FILTER EXISTS { ?x rdf:id ?mid .FILTER(?mid!=\"G1M4\") } }";
```

Answer (score 0):

`EXISTS` was introduced in SPARQL 1.1.

The versions of Androjena I found with quick searching were ancient from around 2010, well before SPARQL 1.1.

Either port a newer version of Jena to support this SPARQL 1.1 feature, or rewrite the query to get the results you want without the construct.